# Merging different react packages into one package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, lerna

I have a monorepo (using lerna) with multiple react apps.
Each react app has its own package.json file and react router. each app basically represents a single page with inner routes and the build command outputs a bundle.js file for each app.
My apps are being served independently in an .aspx pages that import the build output (bundle.js).

I have a "dev" command for each of the apps which runs `webpack-dev-server` so I can debug each app (page) independently.

I want to find a way to debug my entire app (navigating between pages) outside the .net pages. The problem is that each app is isolated (with its own index.html and bundle.js) and is not aware to the other pages.

Is there a way of doing this somehow with express server or anything else?